# ¿Cómo imprimir desde C++ en una impresora?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, impresión

he buscado información acerca de imprimir a través de código de `C++`. Y estoy tratando de usar este código en `Codeblocks`, para poder ordenar imprimir a la impresora:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{

    char const * const pszPrinterName = "LPT1:" ;

    ofstream prn( pszPrinterName );

    if ( ! prn ) {
        cerr << "ERROR: No se puede abrir " << pszPrinterName << '\n' ;
        return 1 ;
    }

    prn << "Hola mundo!" ;

    prn << '\r' // Retorno de carro 
    << '\f' ; // Expulsa la ultima hoja de la impresora

    prn.close();

    return 0;
}
```

La impresora se encuentra correctamente instalada y conectada, el programa lo compila exitosamente, el problema es que no envía impresión.

Nunca había impreso antes por medio de `C++`, alguien me puede guiar si esta es la forma correcta, y que estaré haciendo mal. Gracias.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, `LPT1:` es **puerto paralelo 1**. Para impresora, era `PRN:`, y no estoy seguro de que funcione *hoy en día*. Lo anterior es si estas en windows; desde linux es `/dev/lp`, aunque lo común es usar CUPS, que es otra historia.

Comment: Si, eso temía. Ya verifique el puerto es USB001. Pero igual no me imprime. CUPS se puede usar en windows o solo en Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hola ya pude imprimir con API Windows. Lo que deben hacer es colocar en Dev-C++ el siguiente código:

```
//Ejemplo
#include <windows.h> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

typedef std::basic_ifstream<TCHAR> tifstream; 
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring; 

void Outtextxy(HDC hdc,int x,int y,tstring Msg) 
{ 
TextOut(hdc,x,y,Msg.c_str(),static_cast<int>(Msg.length())); 
} 

void ShowError(tstring strMsg) 
{ 
MessageBox (NULL,strMsg.c_str(),TEXT("Imprimir"),MB_ICONERROR); 
exit(1); 
} 
void ShowInformation(tstring strText) 
{ 
MessageBox (NULL,strText.c_str(),TEXT("Imprimir"),MB_ICONINFORMATION); 
} 
void PrintFile(tifstream& f) 
{ 
PRINTDLG pd; 
DOCINFO di; 
tstring strLine; 
int y=300; 

memset (&pd, 0, sizeof(PRINTDLG)); 
memset (&di, 0, sizeof(DOCINFO)); 

di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO); 
di.lpszDocName = TEXT("Imprimiendo"); 

pd.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLG); 
pd.Flags = PD_PAGENUMS | PD_RETURNDC; 
pd.nFromPage = 1; 
pd.nToPage = 1; 
pd.nMinPage = 1; 
pd.nMaxPage = 0xFFFF; 


if(f.fail()) 
ShowError(TEXT("Error el archivo no se pudo abrir para lectura")); 

if (PrintDlg (&pd)){ 
if (pd.hDC){ 
if (StartDoc (pd.hDC, &di) != SP_ERROR){ 
cout << "Imprimiendo...\nEspere un momento" << endl; 
StartPage (pd.hDC); 
while(!f.eof()){ 
getline(f,strLine); 
Outtextxy(pd.hDC,500,y,strLine.c_str()); 
y+=100; 
} 
EndPage (pd.hDC); 
EndDoc (pd.hDC); 

} 
else 
ShowError(TEXT("Error: No se pudo comenzar a imprimir.")); 

} 
else 
ShowError(TEXT("Error: No se pudo crear el contexto de dispositivo")); 

} 
else 
ShowInformation(TEXT("Se cancelo la impresion")); 

ShowInformation(TEXT("Termino la impresion correctamente.")); 
} 

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{ 

tifstream in(TEXT("texto.txt")); 
PrintFile(in); 
in.close(); 
return 0; 
}
```

Solo que en propiedades del proyecto, en linker deben ingresar:
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32

(exactamente como se encuentra)

Antes de ejecutar deben crear un documento texto.txt en la carpeta.